# Пример поиска Бойера-Мура массива символов в массиве символов

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

С таблицами смещений и принципом вроде как разобрался. Но сделать программно... Даже не знаю с чего начать, и куда копать. Если не трудно, кто знает, или у кого есть выложите исходники или хотя бы куски исходников. Желательно на Delphi, можно на С, С++, C#.

Comment: [Wiki](http://goo.gl/jmKfD) Там же и реализация.

Comment: алгоритм Бойера-Мура!!!

Comment: Спасибо. Вот тебе и ВУЗ. Алгоритму научили, а название не правильное дали!